# Why does Orochimaru helps Sasuke in the midst of war?

Tags: naruto

Orochimaru claimed that he wanted to take over Sasuke's body, yet he announced that he would help in the war against Madara.

Why did Orochimaru helps him?

Comment: Because he heard Sasuke decide to protect the village.

Comment: Well, Obviously, But why? I thought, he was about to kill Sasuke to get his body, but he failed.

Answer (score 1):

Obito Uchiha's ultimate goal was to place everybody in the **Infinite Tsukuyomi** and lead people to peace through genjutsu, where one can achieve his/her dreams and wishes. That being said, Obito joined Madara because greed had driven people to achieve ultimate power. In the course, his beloved Rin died. Given this, Obito was to trying make sure the greed gets completely eliminated.

Whereas Orochimaru is driven by the greed to master all the jutsu in the world. Obito would not let that happen in the world of **Tsukuyomi**. Therefore he had to participate in the war to keep his greed alive, with this he was not only helping Sasuke but also himself.

*One can also question why Orochimaru took this decision just after Sasuke decided to join war with the will to save.*

Possibly Orochimaru still wants to take Sasuke's body, maybe this was an attempt to win back his trust. Think about it.

Comment: @Miramiel Here is a quote from narutowekia about Hiruzen Sarutobi that would elaborate this answer:

 "Questioning Orochimaru of his intentions when the Alliance mobilised, the Sannin notes that he shows no interest in this war. He, however, noted that Obito's plan to conquer the world will interfere with his experiments, thus deciding to join the fray. "  
  
[Link](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiruzen_Sarutobi)